# Error issuing GET to KSQL server. path:/info when I connect to ksql server

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, ksqldb

I try to use ksql in my local

this is my docker-compose file

```
kafka:
  image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
  container_name: mvtds-transformer-kafka
  depends_on:
    - zookeeper
  ports:
    - "9092:9092"
  environment:
    KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
    KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
    KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
    KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
  volumes:
    - kafka-data:/var/run/docker.sock
```

```
ksqldb-server:
  image: confluentinc/ksqldb-server:0.28.2
  hostname: ksqldb-server
  container_name: ksqldb-server
  depends_on:
    - kafka
  ports:
    - "8088:8088"
  environment:
    KSQL_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8088
    KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9092
    KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_STREAM_AUTO_CREATE: "true"
    KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_TOPIC_AUTO_CREATE: "true"
```

```
ksqldb-cli:
  image: confluentinc/ksqldb-cli:0.28.2
  container_name: ksqldb-cli
  depends_on:
    - kafka
    - ksqldb-server
  entrypoint: /bin/sh
  tty: true
```

I have check the ksqldb server and ksqldb-cli pod are running
then I run this command

```
docker exec -it ksqldb-cli ksql http://ksqldb-server:8088
```

I get the error below

```
Remote server at http://ksqldb-server:8088 does not appear to be a valid KSQL
server. Please ensure that the URL provided is for an active KSQL server.

The server responded with the following error: 
Error issuing GET to KSQL server. path:/info
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException:
        Connection refused: ksqldb-server/192.168.16.9:8088
Caused by: Could not connect to the server. Please check the server details are
        correct and that the server is running.
```

I want to know what should I do to fix this issue